# Instagram access token expiry time

Tags: authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram token for login.

After login, I am getting token also, but that token is not permanent. It will expire after some times. What should we do after token is expired; or how can we know that token will got expired?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Access Token Debugger found here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Enter your User Access Token and click "Debug".  At the bottom, there is a button labeled "Extend Access Token".  That will convert your short-lived token to a long-lived token.  I'm still trying to figure out how to do this programmatically.  If anyone knows, please let me know.  I'm using ColdFusion 9 (yeah I know I'm way behind).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation about Instagram authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

> Access tokens may expire at any time in the future

But in the same page, the doc points out (emphasis mine) :

> Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration time, your
>   app should **handle the case that either the user revokes access, or
>   Instagram expires the token** after some period of time. If the token is
>   no longer valid, API responses will contain an
>   “**error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException**”. In this case you will need to
>   re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token.

In other terms, your app doesn't need to fetch a new token for every request, it just needs to spot API responses with **error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException** in it and requests a new token when it happens.

Instagram doesn't seem to provide usual mecanism of *refresh token* where another token with a much further expiration date allow to request a new access token without the login step again.