# Correct way to display instagram feed with all fields by new Instagram API

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have been displaying facebook feed on my website using Facebook Graph API, I want to do the same to display Instagram feed. But in last month Instagram totally changed things for developers like it's not allowing creating clients here in there developer page - https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ Now I totally messed up.

*I tried Instagram Basic Display API following [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) but I don't see a way to display other media fields like comments and likes counts per photo.*

> So is Instagram Graph API is the solution for this??

**If yes then show me the right direction and it will save my time significantly**. I also noticed in the doc of Instagram Basic Display API that access token expires in an hour which is not expected.

So is regarding access token, as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started), in step 3, is this the right way to generate token and when the token expires?, how to extend it?, I see lack of documentation on extending the token comparing with facebook Graph API's documentation.

Comment: Hi Instagram graph api experts, please look at 2nd comment of Matthew Duke's answer, I need that you confirm me with those queries so that i start coding to display complete instagram feed( with media photo url, media photo like and comment count, others) in my php site using Instagram graph api.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions:

1. Yes, that is the correct method to generate a token
2. According to Instagram, that one hour window for user account(s) is to be expected. There is currently no way to extend it. Even using the debugger method for extending the token life does not work. I've tried quite a few methods. 
   https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

[Instagram access token expiry time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044379/instagram-access-token-expiry-time)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#instagram-user-access-tokens

Resource: 
instafeed.js is a very simple tool once you have the access token.
[Instafeed JS not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767598/instafeed-js-not-loading)

---

Additional info:

As of 2018, Instagram has been significantly curbing their calls to their API, and now, **only Business & Creator** accounts are allowed to use their basic-display-api. You can convert your personal profile to Creator or Business here: https://help.instagram.com/2358103564437429

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api.

The change I think you are talking about is the migration of basic permissions from the legacy instagram api to the new Graph API
https://www.developer-tech.com/news/2019/oct/15/instagram-launches-basic-display-api-deprecate-predecessor/

I hope this helps.

Comment: As far as i got from your answer that i can display comment+like counts per photo using instagram graph api. But you did not help me with practical codes. Also i am still not finding ways to have non-expired access token following here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044379/instagram-access-token-expiry-time

Comment: As i said i am FB graph api expert, and instagram graph api fully integrated instagram with facebook Graph api. So, following instagram graph api doc, it seems if we generate user token(using instagram basic perm:) then it can be extended using token debugger's extend token button or by the way we extend user token using FB graph api. you agree now??.As mentioned in https://www.instagram.com/developer/, am i also in the right direction to display instagram feed with all fields(photo comment/like counts...) by only instagram graph api ?? FYI instagram basic display api can't display all fields

Answer (score 0):

The final answer regarding the issue of short-lived tokens is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens. Facebook had no plans to make extended tokens for Instagram. They closed a thread on their forums regarding this issue https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3109002399171119/ but decided to make the extended tokens available for 60 days ONLY for Facebook. Now you can have a limited day non-expiring token for Instagram too.